# Storing temporary data for queues

Tags: php, laravel-4, message-queue, beanstalkd

I am using beanstalkd and laravel for implementing queues . I just want to process a large array through my worker .

I think passing the large array as a message to beanstalkd is not good practice .

**so I just need suggestion on wether I should store that array in a cache or in database or any other place so that I can access it later .**

Comment: Store the array (serialised) in a cache like redis, with a specific key, then pass that key in the message to the worker, which can then retrieve the data from cache.... perfectly valid way of working

Comment: any issue if I store cache in file system ? or does redis provide some robust feature ?

Comment: File system would need to be a shared drive across multiple servers if your worker is running on a different server to the publisher (nfs or similar), and you wouldn't be able to use a temp file safely because that would be deleted when the publisher script terminated; redis provides options for both persistence and clustering

Comment: But any persistent storage that's accessible to both the publisher and the subscriber/worker would be appropriate

Comment: so storing is cache is better than saving in database . Thanks :)

Comment: That's a matter of personal preference; but I prefer cache for something that is intended to be temporary storage